# How can I use order by and group by in sql?

Tags: php, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

Here is my problem:
I have these tables:

```
felado  fogado  fehide  fohide  datum   olvasott    tartalom
```

felado = sender, fogado = receiver,

I would like to get all where felado or fogado is me and group the lines. So If there are the next lines

```
sender 1 receiver 2 id 1
sender 1 receiver 2 id 2
sender 1 receiver 2 id 3
sender 2 receiver 1 id 4
```

I only would like to get one from these lines, the last by ID.

Now I'm trying like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM belso_levelezes 
WHERE (felado="'.$_SESSION["userData"]["id"].'"
   or fogado="'.$_SESSION["userData"]["id"].'" )
ORDER BY id DESC 
GROUP BY felado, fogado
```

It gaves me only one from all, but not the last records. How can I get the last records from each group? 
I want to get only this:

```
sender 2 receiver 1 id 4
```

Comment: Can I actually only get that row? Or I have to use some other solution?

Comment: Never, never just use data from outside (like $_SESSION) in a sql query. Everybody on the internet can manipulate your database, it is called sql-injection. See http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a subquery to create two columns that are unique per conversation.  You can then group on those columns, and grab the maximum id for the conversation.  The example assumes your user id is 42:

```
SELECT  sr1
,       sr2
,       max(id)
FROM    (
        SELECT  case when Sender < Receiver then Sender else Receiver end as sr1
        ,       case when Sender > Receiver then Sender else Receiver end as sr2
        ,       id
        FROM    YourTable
        WHERE   42 in (Sender, Receiver)
        ) as SubQueryAlias
GROUP BY
        sr1
,       sr2
```

Comment: That's almost that. It gives me the last where the sender or receiver is me. But what is there are more contacts? I mean if I'm the sender in 5 line, but there are 3 receiver. Than I need 3 line. Or if there are 5 line where I'm the receiver but not the same senders, than I need 5 line to get. I'm sorry, my english is a bit poor... that's why i tried group by..

Comment: Updated the answer in case you are looking for the last id per conversation

Comment: SenderReceiver1 (aka sr1) would contain the first one of Sender and Receiver when alphabetically ordered

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT MAX(id),felado,fegado,... FROM belso_levelezes WHERE (felado="'.$_SESSION["userData"]["id"].'" or fogado="'.$_SESSION["userData"]["id"].'" ) GROUP BY felado, fogado '
```

Comment: I can't use group by after order by. I know I tried it first, but it give me syntax error for SQL.

Comment: how about without `order by`